# Eclipse Run jar file in cmd where class descrition is in different junit class

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a Junit class which runs individually. Now for creating a jar file a i have created a different java class in same package. And in that class i have mentioned `junit` class name as `JUnitCore.runClasses(IMageCredit.class)`; 
Manifest file is ok.
when i am running jar file using cmd it is showing following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rahul/IMageCredit
                                at rahul.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:11)
                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rahul.IMageCredit
                             at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
                             at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
                             at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                             at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                             at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                             ... 1 more
```

Comment: Is there a file `rahul/IMageCredit.class` in the JAR archive? And which JAR specifically are you running? Show us the command line, please.

Comment: Command line is C:\Users\Me>java -jar Imgcode.jar

Comment: and rahul is pakage name and TestRunner is main class and IMageCredit is  junit class which i am calling in TestRunner class

Comment: Is there a file `rahul/IMageCredit.class` in the JAR archive `Imgcode.jar`?

Comment: yes there is a class with this name "IMageCredit.Class"

Comment: Is it in the correct folder?

Comment: I have created a different jar file and its working. Don't know how.   Its better late than never.